# Não consigo compilar um simples "Olá mundo" em c++ no Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Eu usava o vs code para escrever programas em c++, mas agora baixei e instalei o Visual Studio, porem quando eu tento construir um simples "Olá mundo!" ele dá 478 erros.
Aparentemente ele não está encontrando arquivos de cabeçalho, pois grande parte dos erros são como:
cannot open source file "ctype.h".
Este é o programa:

```
#include "iostream"

int main(){

std::cout << "Ola, mundo!" << std::endl;

return 0;
}
```

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está uma print do erro

Answer (score -1):

- Clique no mouse esquerdo na lâmpada da linha de erro
- Clique `Edit Include path`
- Então nessa janela [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Basta definir o caminho para o gcc
  Caso esse seja seu problema, se você puder adicionar o print do erro que está enfrentando

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).